# Oracle function Returning 1 even if the condition is not satisfied

Tags: oracle, plsql

```sql
Create or replace function abc(row_id in number) return number
as
  id_count number;
Begin

Select count (distinct column_name)
into id_count
from students_table
where class='A1' and row_id=row_id and grade='a' ;

Return id_count ;

End abc;
```

Now even if I pass a row_id whose class and grade is 'b1' and 'b' respectively, still the function returns 1 but it should return 0 as with that row_id there is no matching class and grade conditions.

Can anyone suggest

Comment: `and row_id = row_id`, really? That will be true for most rows.

Answer (score 1):

Don't name PL/SQL variables (or, in this case, function arguments) with the same name as the column.

```sql
Create or replace function abc(
  p_row_id in STUDENTS_TABLE.ROW_ID%TYPE -- use a different name.
) return number
as
  id_count number;
Begin
  Select count (distinct column_name)
  into   id_count
  from   students_table
  where  class='A1'
  and    row_id=p_row_id        -- don't use "row_id = row_id"
  and    grade='a';

  Return id_count;
End abc;
/
```

If you use `row_id = row_id` then its the same as a `1 = 1` condition as Oracle does not know that you intended the left-hand side to be the column value and the right-hand side as the function argument and will use the same value on both sides of the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the parameter of the function so that it does not match the column name.

e.g.

```
Create or replace function abc(P_row_id in number) return number
```

The predicate

```
where class='A1' and row_id=row_id and grade='a'
```

is interpreted as

```
where class='A1' and students_table.row_id=students_table.row_id and grade='a'
```

So the function return all rows with the restricted `class` and `grade` where the `row_id` **IS NOT NULL** - which is basically what you observe.